# Get date from datetime string in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, filter

How can I write filter function for get date from datetime string in angularjs

My date string is

```
2015-03-17 00:00:00
```

I want to get only `2015-03-17`.

My code is,

```
<span class="pull-right"> {{quotationDetails.quotation_date| date : "yyyy-MM-dd" : "'+0430'"}} </span>
```

but it is not working,display nothing.How it resolve?

Answer (score 1):

You can get required output by below changes, Date format and Timezone don't require double quotes instead enclose them only in single quotes as in below example.

```
<span class="pull-right"> {{quotationDetails.quotation_date| date : 'yyyy-MM-dd' : '+0430'}} </span>
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a string. Date filter takes a ***Date object***, **milliseconds** (string or number) or various **ISO 8601 datetime string** formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). As pointed out in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Try setting quotationDetails.quotation_date to `new Date('2015-03-17 00:00:00')`

Here is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/p3ptpOGz82zo03SIOpOh?p=preview)

Comment: how can I use new Date inside ng-repeat for an input value?

Comment: @ShihabudheenMuhammed you could just use type="date" for your input field. Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/p3ptpOGz82zo03SIOpOh?p=preview) and the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D) and there is also [datetime](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdatetime-local%5D) and this is recommended by the angular team for date input

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the `quotation_date` first, try this:

```
function Scoper($scope) {
    var string = "2015-03-17 00:00:00";
    $scope.quotationDetails = {
        dateNow: Date.now(),
        stringDate: string,
        quotationDate: Date.parse(string)
    }
}
```

Here is the working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rainercedric23/aubmfogv/4/

Comment: where should I put this function? or how can I invoke?

Comment: where did you get your data exactly? you can just create another variable that is equal to your string Date like `quotationDate= Date.parse(string)` please see my fiddle so you can play the code the way you want.

Comment: Have I answered your question? if yes, please accept it, Thanks! or if there's lacking just tell me..

Comment: not resolved.I want to use like as a filter.how can I use this function as filter?

Comment: As in you want an input date then it will function as a filter to that input? Am I right?